# Cursor blink in second line of textarea

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

When a button is clicked automatically a timestamp will be added in textarea 1st line.I want the cursor in textarea to blink in second line but for me but it's blinking at the start of the timestamps.How to do this?
I am developing in angular and typescript

Comment: You need to set the cursor position, using `selectionStart` property, like that:
`element.selectionStart = timestamp.length + 1`

Comment: @ViewChild("myinput") myInputField: ElementRef;
myFunction(){
    this.date=new Date();
    let latest_date =this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') ;
    const textArea = this.myInputField.nativeElement as HTMLTextAreaElement;
    //let pos = textArea.textContent.indexOf('\n');
     textArea.selectionStart=latest_date.length+1;
     textArea.focus()
   }
I tried like this but it moves one step forward not coming to the second line

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("txt").value = "yourtext\n";`

Comment: I am passing the timestamp using string interpolation.And this type we can use it in JS but  I am using TS.

Comment: no difference , u can use ngModel

Comment: It worked..Thanks a lot.I am struggling from morning to find this.